# Как в python в список добавить заданное количество списков? (если это возможно)

Tags: python

Допустим, мне нужно распределить слова на заданное пользователем количество "групп", как мне это сделать ?

Я думаю может сделать "генератор" списка в списке, который будет создавать их по заданному количеству..

Comment: Приведите пример работы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483182/python-split-list-into-n-chunks/53868627

Comment: Ну хоть что-нибудь, пока это очень абстрактно всё звучит. Что делить и на как делить не очень понятно

Comment: не понятно, что вообще нужно вот пример создания списка пустых списков a = [[] for i in range(10)]

Comment: "Вы вводите с клавиатуры любое количество слов (оканчивая его ключевым сочетанием “конец списка”), после чего вводите одно целое число – число групп. Слова на группы надо разбить так, чтобы в каждой группе было одинаковое количество слов." ну как-то так..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = []
while True:
    input_ = input()
    if input_ == "exit":
        break
    arr.append(input_)

x = int(input())

for i in range(0, len(arr) + 1, x):
    print(arr[i:i + x])
```